# Setting the Accuracy of calculations

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I need to optimize an expression that involves a number of trigonometric functions and `Exp[]`. How do I make sure that all my calculations have an accuracy of 120-200 digits after the decimal point? This includes the accuracy of `Exp[]` and trig functions.

To get my point across, here is part of the equation:

```
z[x_, y_]:= Exp[Sin[60.0*x]] + Sin[50.0*Exp[y]]
```

Mathematica lets you control `Precision` of computations (which is total number of digits in the number) with two global variables: `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision`. However, I am not looking for precision.

Comment: Do you know that keeping expressions in terms of integers and rationals will keep *exact* values? Try `NestList[16 # (1 - #)/3 &, 1/5, 4]` ? Though for heavy computations you will lose speed.

Comment: I am aware that Mathematica will give me exact values for integer & rational calculations, but my calculations are far from exact.

Comment: It seems that `N[expr, {Infinity, accuracy}]` might be the way to go, assuming the inputs are known to sufficient precision.  (If the inputs are aren't, then you cannot know the result to the desired accuracy.)

Answer (score 5):

How about something like

```
z[x_, y_] := Exp[Sin[60*x]] + Sin[50*Exp[y]]
z[SetAccuracy[20., 200], SetAccuracy[20., 200]] // Accuracy
```

does this not do what you need?

Comment: `In[8]:= z[SetAccuracy[20., 200], SetAccuracy[20., 200]] // Accuracy

Out[8]= 13.6508` Don't think it worked.

Comment: @newprint Sorry, I forgot to add the modified definition of `z` I used. Or, is it that you simply don't know the coeffs? Because that's different...

Comment: Thanks, I understood the `SetAccuracy` and `// Accuracy`

Answer (score 4):

If you use inexact constant in your equation it helps if you increase their accuracy as well. You can do that easily using the backtick notation:

```
z[x_, y_] := Exp[Sin[60.0`200*x]] + Sin[50.0`200*Exp[y]]
z[SetAccuracy[20., 200], SetAccuracy[20., 200]] // Accuracy
```

> 190.0318717

Comment: Initially, I used the backtick for floating point values as well(I read about in Mathematical Cookbook), though it becomes somewhat cumbersome within long equation.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

If you want *Mathematica* to return arbitrary-precision calculations with (approximately) a given Accuracy you could ask for it in `MantissaExponent` form:

```
MantissaExponent[Exp[150] 123``50][[1]] // Accuracy
```

> ```
> 52.8558
> ```

---

#### Supporting information

Accuracy of input numbers can be set with double backticks:

```
12345.5678``50   // Accuracy
12345``50        // Accuracy
```

> ```
> 50.
> 50.
> ```

Single backticks define Precision:

```
12345.5678`50   // Precision
12345`50        // Precision
```

> ```
> 50.
> 50.
> ```

A "constant accuracy" doesn't make much sense for floating point calculations.  *Mathematica* tracks and preserves *Precision*.  This is called "arbitrary-precision" after all.

```
Exp[150] 123`50  // Precision
Exp[150] 123``50 // Accuracy
```

> ```
> 50.
> -15.1442
> ```

Comment: I think in the "Short answer" section you use wrong formulation because `MantissaExponent` does not alter the accuracy of the result (I know, you know it - just for correctness). The right formulation could be: "If you want *Mathematica* to give you the accuracy of the result of calculations you could ask for it using `MantissaExponent` form: ..."

Comment: @Alexey I wasn't sure how to say what I wanted to.  I'll try to rephrase it as you suggest later today.

Comment: One problem is that Wolfram's understanding of *precision* and *accuracy* is significantly misleading and the second one is that you use in this sentence the term "accuracy" with another meaning: the number of precise digits right to the decimal point in `ScientificForm`. In other words, it is something always approximately equal to `Precision` minus 1.

Comment: Discussion on `Precision` and `Accuracy` in *Mathematica*: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/zgddT35SBwc/CahL98krqzsJ